# Why is ?android:attr/textColorPrimary black in night mode notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-night-mode

I'm trying to implement night mode for my app.

In my whole app, `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` is white in night mode and black in day mode. Just in my notifications it's always black. In the Android Studio layout preview the text is white. (I'm sending the notifications from a foreground service if that's relevant.)

I could make a night mode layout file for the notifications where I use `@color/white` for the text but why doesn't it work with attributes?

Comment: Do you have a seperate @colors/Night resource file or are you depending on the OS?

Comment: ``?android:attr/textColorPrimary`` isn't a custom attribute so I expect the OS to handle that. For my notification layout I have a single file with ``?android:attr/textColorPrimary``. I've also tried to use an extra night layout with ``?android:attr/textColorPrimary``. Both don't work. It only works if I set the text color to ``@color/white`` in the night layout and ``@color/black`` in the day layout file.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the reason. I had to set the notification layout's theme to Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer of @Colin, this is an example snippet, how its done:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```